# Solving permutation group equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Assume we are in $S_7$. Let $\alpha^3=(1,2,3,4)$. How to solve for $\alpha$?

This is what I did:

$\alpha^3=(1234)$ implies that after $3$ transformations $1 \mapsto 2$. So, begin by letting $\alpha = (1,a,b,2)$. We also know that $2 \mapsto 3$. So, $\alpha = (1,a,3,2)$. And finally, since $3 \mapsto 4$, $\alpha = (1,4,3,2)$. It can easily be verified that that is a solution.

**Edit:**
<strike>This process didn't seem to work for the case when</strike> Actually, $\alpha^4 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$ does work using the technique (see Arthur's answer). However, it still doesn't produce all solutions.

So, is there a general technique to solve the equation? Moreover, is the a general technique for solving $\alpha^n = (a_1,a_2,...,a_m)$ when $\alpha \in S_j$?

Comment: You missed the two solutions $\alpha=(1432)(567)$ and $\alpha=(1432)(576)$

Answer (score 1):

Where is the problem with using your approach? Starting with $(1, *,*,*,*,*,*)$, since $1$ after four applications becomes $2$, we must have $(1,*,*,*,2,*,*)$. Further applications give, in order
$$
(1,3,*,*,2,*,*)\\
(1,3,*,*,2,4,*)
$$
And so on. At last, we get $(1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6)$.

In general, it's not so easy to calculate, and there are often several solutions. Especially if the disjoint cycles in $\alpha^n$ have length that divide $n$, such as $$\alpha^4 = (12)(34)(56)(78)$$ in $S_8$.

Comment: You're right about the $a^4$ - I made a simple mistake. However, that technique still doesn't produce all solutions. Is it possible to do so with any technique? Or does brute force have to be used?

Comment: A good combination might work. If your method can produce a solution, then it's often pretty easy to figure out a few more. But in the end, you won't be able to tell if you've gotten them all without some further machinery.